# Помогите с запятой 12

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

**Ты случайно не знаешь(,) какие книги нам задавали?**
**Ты случайно не знаешь(,) чего нам задали?**

Comment: А ваше мнение? В чем сомнения?

Comment: "Чего нам задали" - неправильно. "Нам задали" требует винительный падеж: нам задали что? - главу первую/теорему Ферма. Если с родительным падежом - "нам задали берёзовой каши".

Comment: @ddbug, а если заданий несколько?

Comment: Винительный падеж, множественное число.

Comment: *"Нам задали" требует винительный падеж* - Это из серии "нарочно не придумаешь"? Вы даже управление слова "требует" неправильно понимаете. Объясняю. Грамматически правильно: *"Нам задали" требует Винительного **ого** падеж***а***. А по сути тут не все так однозначно. И "чего" вместо "что" вполне возможно в разговорной речи, и "задали"  может управлять родительным.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложное предложение, его части отделяются друг от друга запятой. В первой части подлежащее - ты, сказуемое - знаешь, во второй части подлежащее отсутствует, сказуемое - задали.